# Left Join return not all row

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables: `baseresulttables` and `historyviewdemands`.

I want to get the first n entries from `baseresulttables`, and if there are values for them in `historyviewdemands`.

But the query works like an inner join.

What am I doing wrong?

**baseresulttables**

```
ID    TypeResult
792     1
9397    1
9398    1
9399    1
9400    1
```

**historyviewdemands**

```
ID    BaseResutlTableId
7720    9397
7721    9398
7722    9399
7723    9400
7724    9401
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    bs.ID, hv.Id
FROM
    baseresulttables bs
        LEFT JOIN
    historyviewdemands hv ON (bs.ID = hv.BaseResutlTableId)
WHERE
    bs.`TypeResult` = 1
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

**reuslt**

```
bs.ID   hv.Id
9397    7720
9398    7721
9399    7722
9400    7723
9401    7724
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless, because you aren't telling MySQL which *order* to use for choosing a certain number of records.  Add an `ORDER BY` clause to query for best results.

```
SELECT bs.ID, hv.Id 
FROM baseresulttables bs 
LEFT JOIN historyviewdemands hv
    ON bs.ID = hv.BaseResutlTableId
WHERE
    bs.TypeResult = 1
ORDER BY <some column>
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: I think the `ORDER BY` is the most likely to fix this issue indeed!

Comment: @Pepper I'm not really sure, I'm putting both possibilities in my answer.  Let the OP provide feedback.

Comment: Yes thank you. Already he figured out before your answer. but thanks exactly. he chose a value, he simply made a limit, yielded data on an incomprehensible sorting and the desired value was at the end somewhere ..